# Stopping a dynamic Boostrap affix div from growing over the footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap affix div acting as a kind of clipboard for items selected from a long list. It floats up and down the lefthand side of my page in a pleasing way, but when the user selects enough items from the bottom of the list, the div grows under the footer.
What is the correct way to monitor the size of the affix div and keep it from getting longer than its container?

There's a jfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/bacase96/ to illustrate what I mean. The relevant bit of Javascript that grows the clipboard div is

```
$( ".foo-to-clipboard.selectable" ).click(function() {
    var foo = $( this ).closest('tr').find('.foo-name');
    var foo_id = this.id.substr(4);
    if (selected_foos.indexOf(foo_id) != -1) {
        return;
    }

    $( this ).removeClass('selectable');
    $("#selected-foos").find("tbody").append(
        '<tr><td><i class="fa fa-times red" id="clipboard-' + foo_id +
        '"></i></td><td>' + foo.html() + "</td></tr>");

    selected_foos.push(foo_id);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css:

```
.clipboard {
    overflow:auto;
    max-height:240px  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bacase96/5/